# I have to parse Dynamic json

Tags: json, gson

I am currently working on an android project that requires me to invoke a web service that will return me a json file. I have been using GSON library and Retrofit to parse all the json file and get a JSON object. It has been working well until I come across this json data which the key fields are dynamic. and the value may be a String or an Object

```
{ 
    "attendance":
    {
        "2019-06-01":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-02":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-03":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-04":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-05":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-06":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-07":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-08":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-09":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-10":"holiday:Eid-ul-Fitr",
        "2019-06-11":"Absence",
        "2019-06-12":"Absence",
        "2019-06-13":"Absence",
        "2019-06-14":"Absence",
        "2019-06-15":"Absence",
        "2019-06-16":"Absence",
        "2019-06-17":"Absence",
        "2019-06-18":"Absence",
        "2019-06-19":"Absence",
        "2019-06-20":"Absence",
        "2019-06-21":"Absence",
        "2019-06-22":"Absence",
        "2019-06-23":"Absence",
        "2019-06-24":"Absence",
        "2019-06-25":"Absence",
        "2019-06-26":"Absence",
        "2019-07-03":"Absence",
        "2019-07-04":"Absence",
        "2019-07-05":"Absence",
        "2019-07-06":"Absence",
        "2019-07-07":"Absence",
        "2019-07-08":"offday",
        "2019-07-09":"Absence",
        "2019-07-10":"Absence",
        "2019-07-10":{  
            "attendance_type":"fixed",
            "office_entry_time":"07:02:05",
            "office_out_time":"15:35:07",
            "worked_have_todo":"14:00:00",
            "worked_has_done":"08:33:02",
            "late_in_time":null,
            "early_leave_time":null,
            "working_diffrent":"00:33:02",
            "working_diffrent_sign":"+",
            "location":{  
                "in":"B",
                "out":"B"
            }
        },
        "2019-07-11":{  
            "attendance_type":"fixed",
            "office_entry_time":"07:02:05",
            "office_out_time":"15:35:07",
            "worked_have_todo":"14:00:00",
            "worked_has_done":"08:33:02",
            "working_diffrent":"00:33:02",
            "working_diffrent_sign":"+",
            "location":{  
                "in":"B",
                "out":"B"
            }
        }
    },
    "total":{  
        "total_worked_have_todo":"64:0:0",
        "total_worked_has_done":"73:28:3",
        "total_worked_day":8,
        "avarage_worked_has_done_per_day":"9:11:0"
    }
}
```

Please Help me ... I am absulately confuse ....!
Respect in Advance...

Comment: Java ? In JavaScript you can iterate by for(var in/of .attendance).

Comment: Have you tried using a Map? Retrofit supports it

Comment: i have to parse this json to java object... i used Gson Retrofit.... somebody say that json formed wrong structure... but i have to parse this structure... can i parse this...@Fred

Comment: i have to parse this json to java object...@Tom

Comment: Thanks @IMS0P for edit code...